# Nearby places in open street map in android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

How can I show the nearby places like police station, restaurant in open street maps . I am using [this](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) library to integrate open street map in my android app.  The way I integrate this library is following

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
    map.setUseDataConnection(true);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.8583, 2.2944);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) to download nearby POIs via [OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider). For deciding which POIs to download look at OSM's [map features](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) and corresponding [keys](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) like *amenity*, *shop*, *leisure* and so on.